# Detect power_supply online status for different device in udev rule

Tags: udev

In order to save battery power, I enable runtime PM for all devices using a variant of this rule set:

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="powersave_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", GOTO="powersave"
LABEL="powersave"
TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
LABEL="powersave_end"
```

My Logitech Unifying mouse however has issues with this mode, causing input events to me dropped. When running on battery, I often just use the touchpad or can live with this issue, but when on mains, I would like to disable runtime PM (`ATTR{power/control}="on"`).

It looks like I can use `SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", ATTR{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1"` to match power supply changes, but since the power supply device is not a parent of the USB mouse, it cannot simply be matched.

So, how can a udev rule be written such that it matches a property of a different device?